# Google PubSub Simultaneous Publish Requests

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

In Google PubSub, the publish call from the client can be called asynchronously. Because of this, I would think that it would be possible to have multiple publish requests triggered and sent to the server, all at the same time, especially if the batch thresholds are too low.

If this is true, how does the pubsub client control the number of simultaneous publish requests that can be created?  Is there a hard limit, or an error that can occur if too many requests are created? Is this the intended use of having an asynchronous publisher, or is simply to allow for other non-publishing activity to occur?

Though this question applies to any of the clients, we are specifically having an issue with the C# client, and are intermittently receiving the following error:

```
 Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode=DeadlineExceeded, Detail="Deadline Exceeded")
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCallRetryExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_0`2.<<WithRetry>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

My thought is that we are sending too many publish requests..., but I am not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advice using the raw gRPC code, but use the client library that has a very thin wrapper.

Looking at the client source code always helps me, you can find for c# code here [PublisherClient.cs (thin wrapper)](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-dotnet/blob/master/apis/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1/PublisherClient.cs)

If you are using PublishAsync it queues/batch the messages anyway, the behaviour is controlled the settings you give to the client (see PublisherServiceApiClient for how to tune it). You can also control the number of client connections that are used to send the queues in the client. I suggest playing with the batch-size first, then the number of connections till you found your sweet spot for your throughput.