# Confluent Schema Registry as a stand alone service

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

Can Confluent Schema Registry used by applications outside of Kafka Streams? I am specifically interested in using this component with message queues other than Apache Kafka, such as Cloud Pub/Sub. Based on investigations the component seem like tightly coupled with applications using Confluent Platform.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to define a schema for Google Pub/Sub topics like in Kafka with AVRO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53200289/is-it-possible-to-define-a-schema-for-google-pub-sub-topics-like-in-kafka-with-a)

Comment: If I understand the products correctly, the Hortonworks Schema Registry might work better in GCP if you are using CloudSQL databases (schemas there are stored in the database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the Confluent Schema Registry does *depend* on Kafka (it's where the schemas are actually stored). You don't need the rest of Confluent Platform.

While there is a `Storage` interface that could, in theory, be re-written against an external system, I am not aware of a way to change out the default implementation.

Once you had Kafka (and subsequently Zookeeper), the REST API itself could be wrapped by any external serialization library. Flink, NiFi, and StreamSets for example, have taken this approach for Avro schema management.